# What is wrong with the 'when' clause?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_CAR_DETALS
AFTER UPDATE ON BOOKING_DETALS
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME),NULL) <> 'NULL' OR 
  NEW.BOOKING_STATUS ='C')
```

Comment: When does not exists in isolation in mysql - did you intend a case statement? AND that's a very incomplete trigger - what are you trying to do? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_CAR_DETALS
AFTER UPDATE ON BOOKING_DETALS
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME),NULL) <> 'NULL' OR 
  NEW.BOOKING_STATUS ='C')
BEGIN
 IF NEW.BOOKING_STATUS ='C' THEN
 UPDATE CAR SET AVAILABILITY_FLAG = 'A' , LOC_ID = NEW.PICKUP_LOC WHERE 
 REGISTRATION_NUMBER = NEW.REG_NUM;
 ELSE 
 IF IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME),NULL) <> NULL THEN
 UPDATE CAR SET AVAILABILITY_FLAG = 'A' , LOC_ID = NEW.DROP_LOC, 
 MILEAGE = MILEAGE+GET_MILEAGE WHERE REGISTRATION_NUMBER = 
NEW.REG_NUM;
 END IF;
 END IF;
END;

Comment: This is the whole code. I haven't use the case staement.

Comment: What's that when statement supposed to be doing between for each and begin??

Comment: And since you have a multi statement trigger you may need to set delimiters.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: For checking booking_status

Comment: 'For checking booking_status' - NO code can exist between for each row and begin and you use IF in the main body of the trigger and thats what you should do for this supposed condition.. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Multi statements in triggers need a `BEGIN` and `END`

Also when you use query tabs you need also `DELIMITER`

CASE WHEN you would use if you have multiple choices, but you use better IF THEN

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_CAR_DETALS 
AFTER UPDATE ON BOOKING_DETALS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME),NULL) <> 'NULL' OR NEW.BOOKING_STATUS ='C') then 
        BEGIN 
            IF NEW.BOOKING_STATUS ='C' THEN 
                UPDATE CAR SET AVAILABILITY_FLAG = 'A' , LOC_ID = NEW.PICKUP_LOC 
                WHERE REGISTRATION_NUMBER = NEW.REG_NUM; 
            ELSE 
                IF IFNULL(TO_CHAR(NEW.ACT_RET_DT_TIME),NULL) <> NULL THEN 
                
                    UPDATE CAR SET AVAILABILITY_FLAG = 'A' , LOC_ID = NEW.DROP_LOC, MILEAGE = MILEAGE+GET_MILEAGE 
                    WHERE REGISTRATION_NUMBER = NEW.REG_NUM; 
                END IF; 
            END IF; 
        END;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```